# Kindly Assist. I am trying to display text and background color but only the background color displays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Also When importing reactDom from "react-dom", it gives me an error

e.g `import { ReactDOM } from "react-dom"`

Gives the error:
 `ReactDOM' is not exported from 'react-dom' (imported as 'ReactDOM').`

index.js

```
import React from "react"
import { ReactDOM } from "react-dom"
import App from "./App"
import  "./index.css"

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,document.querySelector("#root"))
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>Hello maaaannnnnnnnnn!!!!</div>
  )
}

export default App
```

index.css

```
body{
background: black;
color: white;
}
```

Error in Debug Console: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')`

Comment: the correct imports are like these: ``import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Comment: it's telling you what the error is. You're importing ReactDOM from React itself, which doesn't exist. You mean to import it from the react-dom library

Comment: fixed and Thank you !   :)   I had to remove the parenthesis : `import {ReactDOM}  from 'react-dom'`  to `import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom' `